# Convert a useReducer function into a hook - React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a state updater using useReducer. I would like to make it a hook (strongly typed). Please advice.

```js
interface IState {
  loading: boolean;
  name: string;
}

const initialState: IState = {
  loading: false,
  name: 'Arun'
}

const [state, setState] = useReducer(
  (state: IState, newState: Partial < IState > ) => ({
    ...state,
    ...newState,
  }),
  initialState
);
```

Please advise on wrapping this function into a hook that is strongly typed.

Thanks.

Comment: your useReducer doesn't look right. The reducer's second arg should be an action, not newState. And useReducer returns a dispatcher, a state-setter. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: How would you use this hook? Give us an example of how you would call it and what it should return.